# Seperate Video Streams in TS file

Tags: video, analyzer, mpeg2-ts

I have multiple steams in a **TS MPEG2 file**  but when I try to open it, it only opens 1 specific video within a file. (WMP) 
When I open another it with another program it opens a different stream. Is there a program that allows me to split them and keep them in TS?

Thank you so much

`General
ID                                       : 1283 (0x503)
Complete name                            : G:\TV Shows\x\x.ts
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 15.8 GiB
Duration                                 : 1h 38mn
Start time                               : UTC 2012-05-30 11:02:45
End time                                 : UTC 2012-05-30 12:40:54
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 23.0 Mbps
Network name                             : Seven Network
Country                                  : AUS (2) / AUS (3) / AUS (4) / AUS (5) / AUS (6) / AUS (7) / AUS (8)
Timezone                                 : +10:00:00 / +10:00:00 / +10:00:00 / +09:30:00 / +08:00:00 / +10:00:00 / +09:30:00`

`Video #1
ID                                       : 769 (0x301)
Menu ID                                  : 1332 (0x534) / 1329 (0x531) / 1328 (0x530)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2`

`Video #2
ID                                       : 801 (0x321)
Menu ID                                  : 1330 (0x532)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2`

`Video #3
ID                                       : 817 (0x331)
Menu ID                                  : 1331 (0x533)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2`

`Video #4
ID                                       : 881 (0x371)
Menu ID                                  : 1335 (0x537)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2`

`Audio #1
ID                                       : 770 (0x302)
Menu ID                                  : 1332 (0x534) / 1329 (0x531) / 1328 (0x530)
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1`

`Audio #2
ID                                       : 802 (0x322)
Menu ID                                  : 1330 (0x532)
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1`

`Audio #3
ID                                       : 819 (0x333)
Menu ID                                  : 1331 (0x533)
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3`

`Audio #4
ID                                       : 882 (0x372)
Menu ID                                  : 1335 (0x537)
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1`

`Text #1
ID                                       : 772 (0x304)-801
Menu ID                                  : 1332 (0x534) / 1329 (0x531) / 1328 (0x530)
Format                                   : Teletext Subtitle
Language                                 : English`

`Text #2
ID                                       : 804 (0x324)-801
Menu ID                                  : 1330 (0x532)
Format                                   : Teletext Subtitle
Language                                 : English`

`Text #3
ID                                       : 821 (0x335)-801
Menu ID                                  : 1331 (0x533)
Format                                   : Teletext Subtitle
Language                                 : English`

Comment: Can someone please edit the code above so it looks nice! tried playing around with it but no idea :(

Comment: Did you find any solution?! If TS contain multiple programs (TV programs that captured by DVB-T), how can split it? For example I have a TS file that contain football + cooking + cartoon .How can i split this TS file to 3 mpg files?

Answer (score 1):

To simply extract streams for TS (i.e. demux) you can use [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy). The following command will create `output.mpeg` with the program of index `1`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -y -c copy -map p:1 output.mpeg
```

Note that you can also remux it into a `.ts` file...

Another alternative is `VLC`'s [duplicate](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html#id347397) command line.

Comment: If TS contain multiple programs (TV programs that captured by DVB-T), how can split it? For example I have a TS file that contain football + cooking + cartoon .How can i split this TS file to 3 mpg files?

Comment: You have to identify the program you want to extract via their PMT (Program Map Table) then, use the matching index in the command example.

Comment: Yea, to convert MPTS to SPTS, your comment worked. But to seperate programs in SPTS, how can I do?

Comment: The comment is to get a `.MPEG` from a `.TS`. If I understand correctly you want to generate 3 `.TS` from the MPTS, unfortunately idk how to do this. I assume that you can extract the 3 program and for each of them generate a `.TS`. Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23964980/3194340

Comment: Output extension is not important for me. I just want to extract each program(music,football,cooking) from a SPTS. About that link, there is no documentation to how to use that tools!